# Need: Seamless jQuery event firing after window resize

Tags: jquery, window-resize

I am no Javascript or jQuery expert, and am in need of some help. I have accordions that are stacked for small screens, and then becomes multi-columns for large screens.

For small screens, users can tap the header (Columns) to open the contents beneath (Categories), which will allow users to open up another layer of accordion content (Items).

For large screens, the Columns headers and the Categories content are shown by default, and users can click the Categories to open the Items.

Currently, the script works for both small and large screens, independently. However, if you interact with the accordions and then resize the browser, the script fails to work for the new screen size. You'll have to refresh the page after resizing the browser for the script to work again.

- How do I write my jQuery code so that the script works in both small and large screens after resizing, without having to refresh the page? I'm aware of the `$(window).resize` method but I'm not expert enough to write it so the code functions as expected.

  ```
  $(function() {
      function toggleAccordions() {
          $('.section-grid').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {

              //Expand or collapse this panel
              $(this).addClass('opened');
              $(this).siblings().removeClass('opened');
              $(this).find($('.fa')).toggleClass('fa-plus fa-times');
              $(this).next('.accordion-content').slideToggle('medium');

              //Hide the other panels
              $('.accordion-content').not($(this).next()).slideUp('medium');
              $('.accordion-toggle').not($(this)).find($('.fa')).removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-plus');
          });
      }

      function accordionsContent() {
              $('.section-grid .accordion-content').find('.item-list-level02 ').click(function() {

              //Expand or collapse this panel
              $(this).addClass('opened');
              $(this).siblings().removeClass('opened');
              $(this).find($('.fa')).toggleClass('fa-plus fa-times');
              $(this).next('.item-list-level03').slideToggle('medium');

              //Hide the other panels
              $('.item-list-level03').not($(this).next()).slideUp('medium');
              $('.item-list-level02').not($(this)).find($('.fa')).removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-plus');
          });
      }

      if ($(window).outerWidth() <= 960) {
          toggleAccordions();
      }
      accordionsContent();
  });
  ```

Link to my pen: http://codepen.io/sensaetions/pen/ZGZByE

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$( window ).resize(function(event) {
    if($(window).outerWidth() <= 960){
        toggleAccordions();
    } else{
        accordionsContent();
    };
};
```

This can be help you.